# How to close the Child Windows? in the Selenium WebDriver - By Using the FunctionalClass

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to close the Child Windows? in the Selenium WebDriver - By Using the FunctionalClass
Hi i am using the Selenium Web Driver and Frame Work, In My Application When i click on the

One Link Button, Then Child Window Will be Displaying On the Screen, Now How To close

Child Windows.

```
public class Reports
{
    public void RPS(WebDriver driver) throws Exception
    {
        AllpagesLogins ALP= new AllpagesLogins();
        //Clicking on the Reports Menu Btn-- Use for Menu Button upper and down
        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.RP_Reports_MenuBtn_ID));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element1);
        System.out.println("Clicked on the Reports Menu Btn");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Clicking on the Particular Link Button
        if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Congratulations Sandeep Pushpala!!!")).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Link Button is Displayed");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Congratulations Sandeep Pushpala!!!")).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on the Link Button Which is Displayed");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link Button is Not Displayed");
        }
        //clicking on the First Link Button, It will display the First Child Window
        ////////////////////////////11111111111111
        if(driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.RP_TotalRecipients_LnkBtn_ID)).isEnabled())
        {
            System.out.println("LnkBtnTotalRecipientsID Link Button is Enabled");
            driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.RP_TotalRecipients_LnkBtn_ID)).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on the LnkBtnTotalRecipientsID Button");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link Button is Total Recipients is Not Displayed");
        }
        //clicking on the Second Link Button, It will display the Second Child Window
        ////////////////////////////2222222222222222222
        if(driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.RP_SuccessfullRecipientsData_LnkBtn_ID)).isEnabled())
        {
            System.out.println("SuccessfullRecipientsDataID Link Button is Enabled");
            driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.RP_SuccessfullRecipientsData_LnkBtn_ID)).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on the LinkSuccessfullRecipientsDataID Button");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link Button is SuccessfullRecipientsDataID is Not Displayed");
        }
        //clicking on the Third Link Button, It will display the Third ![enter image description here][1]Child Window
        ///////////////////////////////333333333333333333333333333
        if(driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.Rp_NotSucessfullRecipientsData_LnkBtn_ID)).isEnabled())
        {
            System.out.println("NotSucessfullRecipientsDataID Link Button is Enabled");
            driver.findElement(By.id(ALP.Rp_NotSucessfullRecipientsData_LnkBtn_ID)).click();
            System.out.println("Clicked on the LinkNotSucessfullRecipientsDataID Button");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link Button is Successfully Recipients Data ID is Not Displayed");
        }
        for Closing the Child Windows I am Using This Code
        //Closing the First Child Window
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("First Child Window is Closed");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Closing the Second Child Window
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Second Child Window is Closed");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Closing the Third Child Window
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Third Child Window is Closed");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an utility method to switch to the required window as shown below

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

It will take you to desired window once title of the window is passed as parameter.
In your case you can do.

```
Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");
childDriver.close();
```

and then again switch to parent window using the same method

```
Webdriver parentDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfParentWindow");
```

This method works effectively when dealing with multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to another window using the [switchTo() method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo%28%29):

```
String firstWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
// execute code to open a second window

// close the first window
driver.switchTo().window(firstWindow).close();
```

Comment: By using this Code i am Closing the Parent Window, But i need to close the Child Window,

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> windows = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());//Returning Set
    for (String s: windows) { System.out.println("window: " + s);} // Let's see names
    String parentWindow = windows.get(0); //In my case, I have two windows.
    String childWindow = windows.get(1); 

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow).close();
    driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).close();
```